# [Agora]I want to create a chat user via RESTful API

Tags: agora.io, agora

I'm using Agora.
I want to create a chat user via RESTful API.
However, I am getting a 401 Unauthorized error.
I don't think it's a token expiration error, but I don't understand "Registration is not open, please contact the app admin.".

`Excerpt from the example`

`domain : Project List/Project Detail/Chat - Application Information - REST API`
`appKey : Project List/Project Detail/Chat - Application Information - App Key`

```
private String registerChatUser(String chatUserName) {
        String orgName = appKey.split("#")[0];
        String appName = appKey.split("#")[1];
        String url = "https://" + domain + "/" + orgName + "/" + appName + "/users";

        HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
        headers.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);
        headers.setAccept(Collections.singletonList(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON));
        String token = getToken();
        headers.setBearerAuth(token);
        Map<String, String> body = new HashMap<>();
        body.put("username", chatUserName);
        body.put("password", "123");
        HttpEntity<Map<String, String>> entity = new HttpEntity<>(body, headers);
        ResponseEntity<Map> response;
        System.out.println(entity);
        try {
            response = restTemplate.exchange(url, HttpMethod.POST, entity, Map.class);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new RestClientException("register chat user error : " + e.getMessage());
        }
        List<Map<String, Object>> results = (List<Map<String, Object>>)    response.getBody().get("entities");
        return (String) results.get(0).get("uuid");
    }
```

and received register chat user error : 401 Unauthorized as a result

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When facing "Registration is not open, please contact the app admin." means

> The error message returned because the app token is not included in the request header when registering users.

Refer to agora->chat error code description here: https://docs.agora.io/en/agora-chat/reference/http-status-codes?platform=android#401-unauthorized

And you can refer the "Secure authentication with tokens" doc to get the app token (a token with app privileges) here: https://docs.agora.io/en/agora-chat/develop/authentication?platform=android#call-agora-chat-restful-apis-with-tokens

Hope this helps.